# Can a built-in grill sit on granite, or does it need to be in a stainless steel jacket?

Tags: kitchens, patio, countertops, heat

I bought a [built-in grill](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0070U0KIK) for my outdoor kitchen, and I'm scratching my head now that it is time to install it. I have read that it is important not to set the grill up on flammable materials, that make sense, but does it need to be one of those SS jackets? I was thinking about having the countertop guy install granite all the way around, would that work if it sat on granite?

Also, how critical is it to have ventilation ports around the grill? I didn't know I "needed" them until they were briefly mentioned in the manual, not sure if they are essential, or nice to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following quotes are from the 
[Lion 90000 Series Instruction manual](http://lionbbq.com/wp-content/uploads/20120312-Lion-InstructionEnglish.pdf):

*"Upper and ground level vents must be provided for combustion air on both sides of built-in cabinet."*

*"Upper and lower vents (20 sq in. minimum must be provided) for combustion air on both sides of built-in cabinet."*

When instructions say **must** it is mandatory, not "nice to have".

The manual says the cabinet can be made from any non-combustible material, granite is stone and non-combustible, so it will be fine.